# Impressão Java - DocPrintJob

Tags: java

Tenho este método para fazer impressão:

```
public void imprimir(String texto) {
    PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
    PrintService impressoraPadrao = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    HashDocAttributeSet hashDocAttributeSet = new HashDocAttributeSet();

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream((texto + "\n").getBytes());
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, docFlavor, hashDocAttributeSet);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService printServico = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 300, 200, printService, impressoraPadrao, docFlavor, printRequestAttributeSet);
    if (printServico != null) {
        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printServico.createPrintJob();
        try {
            docPrintJob.print(doc, printRequestAttributeSet);
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Não acontece nenhum erro.

Mas também não imprime, e quando mando a impressão para o PDFCreator a página sai em branco.

Mas se eu mando uma imagem assim imprime normal:

```
public void imprimir(String texto) {
    PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
    PrintService impressoraPadrao = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
    HashDocAttributeSet hashDocAttributeSet = new HashDocAttributeSet();

    try {
         FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\Trab4_Luc\\teste.png");
         Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, docFlavor, hashDocAttributeSet);
         PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
         PrintService printServico = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 300, 200, printService, impressoraPadrao, docFlavor, printRequestAttributeSet);
         if (printServico != null) {
         DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printServico.createPrintJob();
         try {
             docPrintJob.print(doc, printRequestAttributeSet);
         } catch (PrintException e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
         }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Alguém para ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  diferença entre o código que funciona é de

```
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
```

para

```
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
```

Eu sugiro mudar para:

```
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8;
HashDocAttributeSet hashDocAttributeSet = new HashDocAttributeSet();

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream((texto + 
"\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Usando um editor hexadecimal, tenho certeza que ele está enviando isso para a impressora.
**Não posso afirmar que a impressora sabe imprimir o que eu estou enviando.**

Se isso não funcionar para você, então o único caminho, parece ser renderizar o texto em imagem, e seguir com o caminho alternativo que você citou.

Comment: Consegui fazer a impressão... Minha dúvida agora é para enviar comandos ESC/POS para a impressora, criei um tópico com a dúvida, se puder me ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130901/esc-pos-impress%C3%A3o  Obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoLima Marque a resposta como aceita caso tenho solucionado seu problema.